# Extjs 4.2.1 - drag from xtype grid & drop to xtype container

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm building a calendar, where every single day is a container (xtype: "container") containing html DIV with background. There're a lot of them (30-31 per every user on the list).
I also have a list of grid xtype with some source data in it.

My question is simple, does the container support the dropping?
I want to drag a record from grid, drop it on the container and get the dropped record's data along with used container's data.
What would be the best method for doing that, keeping in mind that soon there could be for example 500 containers in the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to Drag and Drop from One grid to another using the [plugin DragDrop](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/docs/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop.1/)

In Extjs 5, It is possible to specify drag and drop zones, as shown in this [example](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/dd/dragdropzones.html).